# Derived Table for single table to fetch correct result Set

Tags: sql, join, conditional-statements, multiple-columns, derived-table

I have a table where i need to fetch a result using derived table .
Display the products which name starts with either ‘S’ or ‘W’ and
 which belongs to Stationary and cost more than 300 Rs .
[image]

I have tried but i got multiple same column . is it correct or how to correct .

```
        select * from
        (
           select * from tblProduct 
           where (P_name like 'S%' or  P_name like 'W%') 
         ) A
         join
         tblProduct t
       on t.P_id=a.P_id
        where a.P_family like '%Stationary%' and a.cost >300
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need a derived table here? You can simply do this:

```
    select * from tblProduct 
    where P_family like '%Stationary%' 
    and cost > 300
    and (P_name like 'S%' or  P_name like 'W%');
```

Comment: Yes thanks Paresh , But can it be possile through derived query

Comment: what output did you get? from your query, I think you will just get double of each column

Comment: maybe you can try specifying the  column names you want instead of select * in both main and sub query.

Comment: Yes we need to try by specifying column

Answer (score 0):

Take it as

```
select order.*,p.p_name from orderTable order left join tblProduct 
where p.P_name like 'S%' or p.P_name like 'W%' and
order.P_family='Stationery' and order.cost>300
```

Now **change** that **orderTable name** as **above table** image given and then you can get Your desired result.

Comment: Mehta : Order table = tblproduct here no order table

Comment: Take it as  tblProduct only and you can left join a single table for fetching result. @sampathacharya